# Debian10でTCP:80ポートを占有しているサービスを停止したい

Tags: debian

## 環境

ホストOS:Windows10 pro
VMS:VMware Player15
ゲストOS:Debian10

## やりたいこと

とあるWEBサービスにかかわる開発環境を再現するため、VMware上でDebian10を使用します。
80ポートを使用したく、Debian10デフォルトで起動されるWEBサービスを停止したいです。
Linuxは詳しくありません。
Ubuntuのほうが使用頻度が高いのですが、Debianはほぼ触れたことがありません。
80ポートを使用してるサービスを停止するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

## やったこと

defaultではDebian10でApache2が稼働しており、TCP:80ポートが使用されておりました。

- apache2の停止・無効化
  　apache2を停止し、サービスを無効にしました。しかし、TCP:80ポートは使用されたままでした。ゲストOSは再起動しました。
- /etc/inetd.confの確認
  　特に80ポートを使用するような設定ではありません。
- httpdの確認
  　psコマンドで確認しましたが、当該デーモンは起動していません。
- netstat -l -p -tの確認

### netstat -l -p -t結果

```
netstat -l -p -t 
(一部のプロセスが識別されますが, 所有していないプロセスの情報は
表示されません。それら全てを見るにはルートになる必要があります.)
稼働中のインターネット接続 (サーバのみ)
Proto 受信-Q 送信-Q 内部アドレス            外部アドレス            状態        PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 localhost:postgresql    [::]:*                  LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 localhost:smtp          [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
```

### psコマンド結果

```
ps -e --sort cmd
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
  1188 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
   531 ?        00:00:00 ModemManager
   525 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager
   506 ?        00:00:00 VGAuthService
  1260 tty2     00:00:00 Xwayland
   515 ?        00:00:00 accounts-daemon
   720 ?        00:00:00 alsactl
  1265 ?        00:00:00 at-spi-bus-laun
  1272 ?        00:00:00 at-spi2-registr
   150 ?        00:00:00 ata_sff
   517 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
   548 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
  2213 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
   920 ?        00:00:00 colord
    14 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/0
    15 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/1
   516 ?        00:00:00 cron
    31 ?        00:00:00 crypto
   524 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
  1207 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
  1270 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
  1421 ?        00:00:00 dconf-service
    35 ?        00:00:00 devfreq_wq
   639 ?        00:00:00 dhclient
    34 ?        00:00:00 edac-poller
  1427 ?        00:00:00 evolution-addre
  1502 tty2     00:00:00 evolution-alarm
  1361 ?        00:00:00 evolution-calen
  1307 ?        00:00:00 evolution-sourc
  1168 ?        00:00:00 exim4
   255 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
   331 ?        00:00:00 fusermount
  1576 ?        00:00:00 fwupd
  1183 ?        00:00:00 gdm-session-wor
  1205 tty2     00:00:00 gdm-wayland-ses
   583 ?        00:00:00 gdm3
  1201 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-d
  1209 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-session-b
  1240 tty2     00:00:04 gnome-shell
  1303 ?        00:00:00 gnome-shell-cal
  1503 tty2     00:00:01 gnome-software
  2208 ?        00:00:01 gnome-terminal-
  1313 ?        00:00:00 goa-daemon
  1326 ?        00:00:00 goa-identity-se
  1376 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-a11y-settin
  1383 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-clipboard
  1380 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-color
  1387 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-datetime
  1517 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-disk-utilit
  1388 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-housekeepin
  1389 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-keyboard
  1393 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-media-keys
  1395 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-mouse
  1347 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-power
  1348 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-print-notif
  1409 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-printer
  1350 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-rfkill
  1352 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-screensaver
  1354 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-sharing
  1362 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-smartcard
  1371 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-sound
  1364 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-wacom
  1363 tty2     00:00:00 gsd-xsettings
  1334 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-afc-volume
  1339 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-goa-volume
  1327 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
  1343 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-mtp-volume
  1316 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-udisks2-vo
  1247 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd
  1252 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-fuse
  1281 tty2     00:00:00 ibus-daemon
  1285 tty2     00:00:00 ibus-dconf
  1447 tty2     00:00:00 ibus-engine-moz
  1286 tty2     00:00:00 ibus-extension-
  1293 ?        00:00:00 ibus-portal
  1290 tty2     00:00:00 ibus-x11
   669 ?        00:00:00 inetd
    88 ?        00:00:00 ipv6_addrconf
   162 ?        00:00:00 irq/16-vmwgfx
    56 ?        00:00:00 irq/24-pciehp
    57 ?        00:00:00 irq/25-pciehp
    58 ?        00:00:00 irq/26-pciehp
    59 ?        00:00:00 irq/27-pciehp
    60 ?        00:00:00 irq/28-pciehp
    61 ?        00:00:00 irq/29-pciehp
    62 ?        00:00:00 irq/30-pciehp
    63 ?        00:00:00 irq/31-pciehp
    64 ?        00:00:00 irq/32-pciehp
    65 ?        00:00:00 irq/33-pciehp
    66 ?        00:00:00 irq/34-pciehp
    67 ?        00:00:00 irq/35-pciehp
    68 ?        00:00:00 irq/36-pciehp
    69 ?        00:00:00 irq/37-pciehp
    70 ?        00:00:00 irq/38-pciehp
    71 ?        00:00:00 irq/39-pciehp
    72 ?        00:00:00 irq/40-pciehp
    73 ?        00:00:00 irq/41-pciehp
    74 ?        00:00:00 irq/42-pciehp
    75 ?        00:00:00 irq/43-pciehp
    76 ?        00:00:00 irq/44-pciehp
    77 ?        00:00:00 irq/45-pciehp
    78 ?        00:00:00 irq/46-pciehp
    79 ?        00:00:00 irq/47-pciehp
    80 ?        00:00:00 irq/48-pciehp
    81 ?        00:00:00 irq/49-pciehp
    82 ?        00:00:00 irq/50-pciehp
    83 ?        00:00:00 irq/51-pciehp
    84 ?        00:00:00 irq/52-pciehp
    85 ?        00:00:00 irq/53-pciehp
    86 ?        00:00:00 irq/54-pciehp
    87 ?        00:00:00 irq/55-pciehp
   518 ?        00:00:00 irqbalance
   254 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sda1-8
    22 ?        00:00:00 kauditd
    33 ?        00:00:00 kblockd
    28 ?        00:00:00 kcompactd0
    20 ?        00:00:00 kdevtmpfs
    30 ?        00:00:00 khugepaged
    25 ?        00:00:00 khungtaskd
    32 ?        00:00:00 kintegrityd
    29 ?        00:00:00 ksmd
     9 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/0
    17 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/1
    98 ?        00:00:00 kstrp
    37 ?        00:00:00 kswapd0
     2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    55 ?        00:00:00 kthrotld
     5 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0-rcu_par_gp
     6 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd
    13 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:1-events
   160 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:1H-kblockd
    24 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:2-cgroup_destroy
   157 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:3-rcu_par_gp
    18 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:0-ata_sff
    19 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd
    23 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:1-events
   212 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:1H-kblockd
   156 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:2-ata_sff
   208 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:3-events
     7 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u256:0-events_unbound
    89 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u256:1-events_unbound
   155 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u256:2-events_unbound
   249 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u257:0
   709 ?        00:00:00 lighttpd
    12 ?        00:00:00 migration/0
    16 ?        00:00:00 migration/1
     8 ?        00:00:00 mm_percpu_wq
  1453 tty2     00:00:00 mozc_server
   149 ?        00:00:00 mpt/0
   148 ?        00:00:00 mpt_poll_0
    21 ?        00:00:00 netns
    26 ?        00:00:00 oom_reaper
   792 ?        00:00:06 packagekitd
   550 ?        00:00:00 polkitd
   609 ?        00:00:00 postgres
   633 ?        00:00:00 postgres
   634 ?        00:00:00 postgres
   635 ?        00:00:00 postgres
   636 ?        00:00:00 postgres
   637 ?        00:00:00 postgres
   638 ?        00:00:00 postgres
  2252 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
  1276 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
    11 ?        00:00:00 rcu_bh
     3 ?        00:00:00 rcu_gp
     4 ?        00:00:00 rcu_par_gp
    10 ?        00:00:00 rcu_sched
   520 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
   751 ?        00:00:00 rtkit-daemon
   151 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_0
   153 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_1
   210 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_2
   152 ?        00:00:00 scsi_tmf_0
   154 ?        00:00:00 scsi_tmf_1
   211 ?        00:00:00 scsi_tmf_2
     1 ?        00:00:01 systemd
  1187 ?        00:00:00 systemd
   295 ?        00:00:00 systemd-journal
   521 ?        00:00:00 systemd-logind
   508 ?        00:00:00 systemd-timesyn
   318 ?        00:00:00 systemd-udevd
  1500 tty2     00:00:00 tracker-miner-a
  1518 tty2     00:00:03 tracker-miner-f
  1515 ?        00:00:00 tracker-store
   159 ?        00:00:00 ttm_swap
   522 ?        00:00:00 udisksd
   560 ?        00:00:00 unattended-upgr
   783 ?        00:00:00 upowerd
   333 ?        00:00:00 vmhgfs-fuse
   510 ?        00:00:00 vmtoolsd
  1519 tty2     00:00:00 vmtoolsd
   315 ?        00:00:00 vmware-vmblock-
    36 ?        00:00:00 watchdogd
   529 ?        00:00:00 wpa_supplicant
    27 ?        00:00:00 writeback
```

Comment: Apache を無効にしたのであれば、いったん ゲスト OS (Debian) 自体を再起動してみるとどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: ポートを使用しているプロセスは `lsof -i :80` を実行すれば確認できると思います。

Comment: ゲストOSの再起動は真っ先に行いました。Apache2の応答していたページはなくなり、403 Forbiddenの表示となりました。netstat -a コマンド結果では、0.0.0.0:httpが存在します。lsof -i:80では何も表示されません。ss -atnでも0.0.0.0：80がLISTEN状態で存在します。

Comment: 1023番以下のポートは特権ポート(privileged ports)なので root 権限で lsof コマンドを実行する必要があります。`sudo lsof -i:80`

Comment: ssも同様で, `sudo ss -tlp sport 80` など指定しないと表示されないはず。ていうか netstatのメッセージにも出てる。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決できたので、記載します。

netstat -l -p -t結果から、自分自身で起動したpostgresqlに対してもPIDの記述がなかったことから、サービス稼働の可能性があるとわかりました。

## 稼働中サービスの確認

### コマンド

```
systemctl list-units --type=service
```

### 結果

```
UNIT                               LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION                                                  
----
...
lighttpd.service                   loaded active running Lighttpd Daemon
...
```

怪しいのがいました。→　lighttpd.service

### サービス停止

```
sudo systemctl stop lighttpd.service
```

見事に解決しました。